# php call c# asp.net webmethod

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, webmethod

I would like to use php to call a c# webmethod but it's unsuccessful - why?

```
    try {

    $client = new SoapClient($VerifyUser);

    $params = array( 
        'Merchant_id'  => $tbl_result['tbl_merchant']['data'][0]->Merchant_id, 
        'Merchant_code' => $tbl_result['tbl_merchant']['data'][0]->Merchant_code
    );

    $response = $client->VerifyUser(
        array(
            'Merchant_id'=>$tbl_result['tbl_merchant']['data'][0]->Merchant_id
        )
    )->VerifyUserResult;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

////////////// C#

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string VerifyUser(string Merchant_id)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

There is an error as below:

> Function ("VerifyUser") is not a valid method for this service

Now i change to below:

```
$clsUser = array( 'xxx' => 'xxx' ); 
$urlWebService = "xxx.asmx?WSDL"; 
$response = WebSoapClient("VerifyUser", $urlWebService, $clsUser); 


function WebSoapClient($function ,$url, $data = array() ) { 
    $response = null; 
    try { 
        $client = new SoapClient($url); 
        $response = $client->__soapCall( $function, $data ); 
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        ErrorLog("WebSoapClient->". $function . " - " . $e->getMessage()); 
    } 
    return $response; 
} 


/C# 
[WebMethod] 
public string VerifyUser(clsUser clsUser) { 
    //xxx...
}
```

but in C# param is null...

Comment: Is the webmethod in an asmx service or aspx, or what? Are you sure it's definitely a SOAP interface? Is there a WSDL?

Comment: Yes it is WSDL. Now i change to below:
 $clsUser = array(
 'xxx' => 'xxx'
 );
$urlWebService = "xxx.asmx?WSDL";
$response = WebSoapClient("VerifyUser", $urlWebService, $clsUser);

function WebSoapClient($function ,$url, $data = array() ) {
$response = null;
try {
 $client = new SoapClient($url);
 $response = $client->__soapCall(
  $function,
  $data
 );
} catch (Exception $e) {
 ErrorLog("WebSoapClient->". $function . " - " . $e->getMessage());
}
 return $response;
}
/C#
[WebMethod]
public string VerifyUser(clsUser clsUser)
{
}

but in C# param is null...

Comment: Ok. So, what was the result of that change? P.s. if you have new code to share, please edit your question - do not put code in these comments where you cannot easily format it, thanks. The "edit" button is at the end of your question just below the little blue tags